# VueJS TypeError: alert is not a function

Tags: vue.js, alert, vue-directives

I'm trying to learn VueJS. I've made my first vue and I'm testing the directives. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Partie 1 Chapitre 3 - Vue Mart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
 
  <button v-on:click="alert('hello')">Cliquez ici !</button>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      costOfApples: 5,
      costOfBananas: 2,
      costOfCoconuts: 8,

      favoriteColor: 'rose'
    },
    //Propriétés calculées
    computed: {
      totalAmount() {
        return this.costOfApples + this.costOfBananas + this.costOfCoconuts
      },
      label() {
        return ': '+ this.favoriteColor
      }
    }
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click my button I get this error:

```
TypeError: alert is not a function
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: alert is not a function"
[Vue warn]: Property or method "alert" is not defined on the instance but referenced during 
render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>)
```

I really don't know where to start looking. To me, my code seems okay.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define alert in your methods

```
methods(){
   alert(){
       // do something      
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see, I thought it would execute like the alert method. but then if I want to reproduce the behavior of the alert method how can I do this? I'm following a tutorial using alert like and they did not define it in their methods, that's why I was asking

Comment: Edit: I called showColor like that `<button v-on:click="showColor">Cliquez ici !</button>` and then I defined a method `showColor (){ alert('hello')}` and it worked. THough, I don't know why it's not working when I directly do `<button v-on:click="alert('hello')">Cliquez ici !</button>` Is it because of the Directives? Thanks!

Comment: @click="()=>{alert('test')}"  this way you could use js alert directly

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same tutorial and they indeed do not explain it.

Here is how I did it :

```
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                //some stuff
            },
            computed: {
                // some other stuff
                }
            },
            methods: {
                alert(message) {
                    alert(message)
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

This is a VueJS v2 tutorial, i think this is not needed in v3